# No Wifi option in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

My ubuntu desktop previously had both wifi and ethernet option. However, there is no wifi detected. OS detects the ethernet controller but wifi controller is no longer detected by system.

I am currently using ethernet at the time of writing.

```
saurav@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
saurav@ubuntu:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
saurav@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: I don't see any wireless adapter. What kind of adapter you are using? Is it a USB dongle, or a built-in one?

Comment: For ethernet try `lspci -knn | grep -i Net -A3` .

Comment: Please post the output of `iwconfig`.

Comment: Is there an option in your EFI/BIOS to enable/disable wireless? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I've got built-in one. I have reformatted the whole OS. And, now it works fine. I now know that it is using Intel Wireless Adapter. But, I would like to not format it everytime the issue comes. So, any suggestion on how to help it?

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: no clues in there. It's like the peripheral doesn't even exist.

Comment: sometimes when I suspend the PC, the same thing happens. I get no wifi adapter found when getting out of suspend mode.